# Toggle special feature in dashboard

Tags: magento-1.7, backend, dashboard

I am trying to create a module for toggling visibility of a sort of welcome announcement or special features announcement banner at the top of the screen on a Magento site (1.7.0.2). I want to be able to toggle the visibility / presence of this banner via a UI element in the backend.

I don't want to have to edit my static blocks (beyond set-up), nor have to have the store owner navigate the backend to disable / enable, beyond a menu item or similar simple UI. Does Magento have any built-in mechanism to allow for this sort of UI control?

Here's some code snippets:

In the CMS, I created a static block with title "Header Hello Block" and id "header_hello_block", which looks like this:

```
<div class="holder">
<div class="hellobar">Hello, world!</div>
</div>
```

and in my `app/design/frontend/default/themename/layout/page.xml` I've entered the following, just after the html_header:

```
        <block type="cms/block" name="header_hello_block" before="-">
            <action method="setBlockId">
                <block_id>header_hello_block</block_id>
            </action>
        </block>
```

According to [this article](http://bradfrost.com/blog/web/magento-static-blocks/), that's all I should need to do in order to see my block rendered. What am I missing?

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: There's no code yet. Just a static block.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `before_body_start` block to add your static block

```
<reference name="after_body_start">
<block type="cms/block" name="unique-name"> 
      <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>your-static-block</block_id></action> 
    </block> 
</reference>
```

Use this code in your local.XML file.

Comment: before_body_start? are you sure about that? I cannot find that in any reference.

Comment: Check page.XML file and template/page/1column.phtml,2columns-left.phtml ,etc files.

Comment: I've done that, and updated my code above. Any hint as to why it's still not working?

Comment: Put your code in `block name="before _body_start"`

Comment: `<block type="page/html_header" name="header" as="header">
                <block type="page/template_links" name="top.links" as="topLinks"/>
                <reference name="before_body_start">
                    <block type="cms/block" name="header_hello_block" before="-">
                        <action method="setBlockId">
                            <block_id>header_hello_block</block_id>
                        </action>
                    </block>
                </reference>
This makes no difference. Do you mean "after_body_start"? I cannot find any  "before" https://goo.gl/NzUNT4

Comment: Sorry, you are right after_body_start

Comment: It's my mistake that is before_body_end.

Comment: <reference name="after_body_start">
                    <block type="cms/block" name="header_hello_block" before="-">
                        <action method="setBlockId">
                            <block_id>header_hello_block</block_id>
                        </action>
                    </block>
                </reference>

Does not render anything on the page, unfortunately.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25948/discussion-between-smittles-and-meenakshi-sundaram-r).

Comment: Check your template file. i.e., 1column.phtml or anything. `$this->getChildHtml(after_body_start)` code is present or not